# Who was Kubja? What was her relationship with Krishna?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana

In Srimad Bhagavata Purana and also in Brahma-Vaivarata Purana there is a story of Kubja, a *dasi* of Kamsa.

Who was that in other scripture and what was her relationship with Bhagwaan Krishna?

I have seen few sites which are misleading about her relationship with Bhagwaan Krishna.

Comment: @TalkisCheapShowmeCode Your Q can't be closed as duplicate of that Q because it does not have any answer yet. There is no need for you to delete your Q IMO.

Comment: Kubjs is pingala in her previous life who did austerities and penance lord vishnu to be her husband in next birth that us lord krishna